# Hibernate transfer data between 2 databases

Tags: database, hibernate

I have 2 databases with the same schema:  local db A and a central one B.
I want to:

1. query for session (with some criteria) from db A
2. insert select data to db B as new entries with a new generated ids.

For example:
session entity has generated id and ManyToOne  relation to testingData which has also generated id.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
public long getDatabaseIdentifier()
{
    return databaseIdentifier;
}
```

What is the best efficient way to do it? I don’t want to create new entities and use copy constructor.
I tried to use `Example.create(session).excludeProperty("databaseIdentifier")` but with no luck.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate a new object (maybe using the copy constructor approach). The problem is that the objects you get back from Hibernate are proxied, and as a consequence, tied to the session (Have you ever got a LazyInitializationException at some point?)

So, you'll need to copy the properties from an hibernate-enhanced object tied to **DB A** to a vanilla object, that is not linked to any DB and can be inserted in **DB B**.

---

### update

You can try the following, but I'm not sure if it might work

- Detach the object by calling EntityManager.detach(obj)
- Remove the ID from the object
- save the object with the other entity manager

Again, I'm not sure if this will work as detach() removes the object from the persistent context, but it's still an enhanced object.

Comment: It might be a huge db and complex data, so I want to avoid the copy constructor